# Working package for fiducial pose recognition?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've been trying to compile the fiducial package (http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=fiducial) without success due to a compilation error in its dependency, opencv_candidate (http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=opencv_candidate).  (I've included the rosmake output below.)  I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 using Diamondback.

Should I be using another package (or other option) for fiducial pose recognition?  Has anyone else had luck compiling the fiducial package, and its opencv_candidate dependency?

Thank you,
Billy McCafferty
http://www.sharprobotica.com/

---

rosmake opencv_candidate:

### [rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv_candidate [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesencv_candidate: 1.3 sec ]                                                                                                                                  [ 1 Active 28/29 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:398: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘crmag’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:399: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ncx’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:400: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ncy’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:402: error: ‘v’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:402: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:402: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:402: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:402: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:403: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ccyxyxA’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:404: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ccyxyxB’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:405: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ccx’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:406: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ccy’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:407: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ccmag’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:408: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ccrmag’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:409: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘nccx’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:410: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘nccy’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:412: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dot’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:414: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘iscand’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘iscand’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘cmag’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘ccmag’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘_mm_min_ps’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘_mm_set_ps’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘_mm_mul_ps’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘_mm_max_ps’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘_mm_cmpgt_ps’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:416: error: ‘_mm_and_ps’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:417: error: ‘dot’ was not declared in this scope
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:417: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:417: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:417: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:417: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/src/datamatrix.cpp:420: error: ‘_mm_store_ps’ was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv_candidate.dir/src/datamatrix.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv_candidate.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lebowski/suijuris/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding/opencv_candidate/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package opencv_candidate written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/lebowski/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110506-235914/opencv_candidate/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv_candidate [FAIL] [ 1.31 seconds ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9914/working-package-for-fiducial-pose-recognition?/) by [Billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/290/billy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2011-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm not sure this is what you need, but have you looked at [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose)?

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2